# Covering space problem from an old Qual

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose that S$^1 \times P^2$
covers some space, and let $h$ be a covering
translation. Show that the induced isomorphism $h$ of $H_1(S^1, P^2)$
must be the identity